# WinHTTP decompression function?

Tags: winhttp

Presently I am using winhttp api in c++ to get data from a server. The server can support various compression formats. So presently I want to use winhttp to get the compressed format (eg gzip) and decompress it. Is it possible to decompress the data using winhttp?
thanks
Harsha